# JSDoc dojo.mixin for Eclipse outline view

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dojo, jsdoc, outline-view

How can I document the following JavaScript code example with `dojo.mixin`, so that Eclipse (version 4.5.2) shows the functions from `SomeClass1` and `SomeClass2` in the Outline View?

```
var de = de || {};
de.namespace1 = de.namespace1 || {};
de.namespace1.namespace2 = de.namespace1.namespace2 || {};

/**
 * @param nodeId
 * @param config
 * 
 * @constructor 
 * @namespace de.namespace1.namespace2.SomeClass1
 */
de.namespace1.namespace2.SomeClass1 = function(nodeId, config) {

  var subClassConfig = {
      prop1: "foo",
      prop2: "bar"
  };

  return dojo.mixin(new de.namespace1.namespace2.SomeClass2(nodeId, config, subClassConfig), {
    /** @private */
    var1 : null,

    /**
     * @public
     * @memberOf SomeClass1
     */
    init : function() {
      // TODO
    }
  });
};
```

How can I get e.g. the `init` function to be shown in the Eclipse outline view?

[image: Eclipse outline view showing no methods / properties if dojo.mixin is used]

Answer (score -1):

What version of Eclipse are you running? I'm running Mars and that piece of code looks fine in the outline here:

[image]

Maybe it helps, but I have the "Dojo Web Tools" from IBM installed.

Comment: I using Eclipse Mars 2. Where can I find IBM "Dojo Web Tools"?

Comment: Do you mean [IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-liberty-developer-tools)? Is it not possible without that package?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this is possible without that package. I have this one installed: [IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v85x-developer-tools).

Comment: I have just installed mars 2 and above package. For this to work you also need to check a Project Facet on your project: Web 2.0 / Dojo Toolkit. Once the Dojo Toolkit facet is installed then the outline will show the init function.